# How many short rooks can be placed on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

Placing rooks on the table is a commonly known problem. What about "short rooks" (they behave in the same manner, but on distance less or equal to 2.
I've noticed that splitting the board into 5x5 smaller ones and using the classical rook placing might help, but knowing the maximum number will allow me to construct a good placement.

Comment: So short rooks on a1 and c1 would threaten each other, but on a1 and d1 they would not?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As seen here, it's possible to place $22$. It's not hard to prove that this is optimal.

Comment: How did you produce the picture so fast?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is an optimal solution, but I have no idea to check this except by writing a computer program that finds the optimal solution. Would you be so kind to sketch a proof for th optimality of this position?

Comment: more than three per row is not possible so 24 rooks is an upper limit.

Comment: three consecutive row can hold at most 8 (=3+3+2) rooks. So you are right, it is simple to proof.